# When a substring isn't found in a string then parse a website

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, parsing, beautifulsoup

Here is my base code:

```
import urllib
import webbrowser
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

address = 'https://google.com/search?q='
# Default Google search address start
file = open( "OCR.txt", "rt" )
# Open text document that contains the question
word = file.read()
file.close()

myList = [item for item in word.split('\n')]
newString = ' '.join(myList)
# The question is on multiple lines so this joins them together with proper spacing

qstr = urllib.parse.quote_plus(newString)
# Encode the string

newWord = address + qstr
# Combine the base and the encoded query

response = requests.get(newWord)

#with open('output.html', 'wb') as f:
#    f.write(response.content)
#webbrowser.open('output.html')

answers = open("ocr2.txt", "rt")

ansTable = answers.read()
answers.close()

ans = ansTable.splitlines()

ans1 = str(ans[0])
ans2 = str(ans[2])
ans3 = str(ans[4])

print(' ')
print(newWord)
print(' ')
print(newString)
print(' ')
print("1. "+ans1)
print("2. "+ans2)
print("3. "+ans3)

ans1Score = 0
ans2Score = 0
ans3Score = 0

soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'lxml')
for g in soup.find_all(class_='g'):

    webBlock = str(g)

    ans1Tally = webBlock.count(ans1)
    ans2Tally = webBlock.count(ans2)
    ans3Tally = webBlock.count(ans3)

    if  webBlock.find(ans1)!=-1:

        ans1Score += ans1Tally

    if webBlock.find(ans2)!=-1:

        ans2Score += ans2Tally

    if webBlock.find(ans3)!=-1:

        ans3Score += ans3Tally

    #print(ans1+": "+str(ans1Score))
    #print(ans2+": "+str(ans2Score))
    #print(ans3+": "+str(ans3Score))
    #print('-----')
    #print(g.text)

print(' ')
print('-----')
print(ans1+": "+str(ans1Score))
print(ans2+": "+str(ans2Score))
print(ans3+": "+str(ans3Score))
print('-----')

#print(g.text)
```

What I basically want to implement is that if the phrase is not found in the block of text (It is a google search result, so it contains the Title, Link, and the small blurb of text. If I print webBlock this is an example of what it contains:

```
<div class="g"><h3 class="r"><a href="/url?q=https://www.rollingstone.com/glixel/news/lists/bloodbowl-and-beyond-the-most-absurdly-violent-football-games-of-all-time-w464896/mutant-league-football-w464904&amp;sa=U&amp;ved=0ahUKEwjSxdiFq5_YAhWlSd8KHSX-DtUQFghKMAk&amp;usg=AOvVaw2e_Z2FBOjUfryPIGK3yhEq"><b>Mutant League</b> Football | 'Bloodbowl' and Beyond: The Most ...</a></h3><div class="s"><div class="kv" style="margin-bottom:2px"><cite>https://www.rollingstone.com/...<b>games</b>.../<b>mutant-league</b>-football-w464904</cite><div class="_nBb"><div aria-expanded="false" aria-haspopup="true" data-ved="0ahUKEwjSxdiFq5_YAhWlSd8KHSX-DtUQ7B0ISzAJ" onclick="google.sham(this);" style="display:inline" tabindex="0"><span class="_O0"></span></div><div class="am-dropdown-menu" role="menu" style="display:none" tabindex="-1"><ul><li class="_Ykb"><a class="_Zkb" href="/url?q=http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search%3Fq%3Dcache:7JwZzaQGVBsJ:https://www.rollingstone.com/glixel/news/lists/bloodbowl-and-beyond-the-most-absurdly-violent-football-games-of-all-time-w464896/mutant-league-football-w464904%252BThe%2B%2522Mutant%2BLeague%2522%2Bvideo%2Bgames%2Bdid%2BNOT%2Binclude%2Bwhich%2Bsport%3F%26hl%3Den%26ct%3Dclnk&amp;sa=U&amp;ved=0ahUKEwjSxdiFq5_YAhWlSd8KHSX-DtUQIAhNMAk&amp;usg=AOvVaw1l8NtEdw1gvsqGLNw13Ulf">Cached</a></li></ul></div></div></div><span class="st">Feb 3, 2017 <b>...</b> In which Electronic Arts realized they still had the durable Madden '93 engine <br/>
lying around, and decide to commit their talents to more than one football <b>game</b> <br/>
every year. <b>Mutant League</b> Football for the Sega Genesis is ridiculous . It takes <br/>
place in a post-apocalyptic wasteland where radiation has mottled ...</span><br/></div></div>
```

What I want to do is if that block of text does not contain the string, I want to extract the link out of it and then do what I did with the original google search link:

Parse the data to collect all of the < p > tags, and then scan to see if the phrase is inside of there and then add it to the tally. It must do this for all of the phrases.

Some problems that I ran into are:

Not all of the links contains http://, https:// or www.. For example, mario.wikia.com. I want to be able to pull the link no matter what it is.

I have been racking my brain on this problem for a while now so I figured I would just throw it up here and see if anybody had any solutions. I am sure that there may be a simple answer but I am new to Python and have a lot of "doh" moments.

Anyways, any help is appreciated and thanks for reading!

Comment: if "substring" not in "some string":
  dowork()

Comment: Yeah I got that part, my problem more is how to extract the URL from webBlock. Thank you for the reply though!

Comment: Isn't the ```<a href=``` tag what you are looking for?

Comment: @bigmacd Yep! It contains the link I am looking for. I just do not know how to extract it from the rest of the text. I assume regex but I do not know how to do it for all links, even ones that do not contain http:// https:// or www. like the example I provided in the original post. I need to extract that link, then with BeautifulSoup parse all of the paragraph tags on that page for each of the phrases as well, but only if the original phrase is not found in the first 'g' class. Thanks for the reply!

Comment: `g` is object similar to `soup` so you can use `g.find_all("a")` or `g.find("a")` to get `a`. Better read [BeautifulSoup documentation](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) - it has many functions to get tags and and parameters so you don't need regex.

Comment: `split()` returns list so you don't need `[item for item in ...]` - do `myList = word.split('\n')`. If you do `newString = ' '.join(myList)` then maybe you shoud do `newString = file.read().replace("\n", " ")`

Answer (score 0):

`g` is object similra to `soup` so you can get url from `a` using the same functions

```
 g.find('a')['href']
```

Full url will be

```
 url = 'https://google.com' + g.find('a')['href']
```

Code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib

def do_something_with_page(url):
    response = requests.get(full_url)

    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'lxml')

    print("... DO SOMETHING WITH THIS PAGE ...")
    print()


# ---------------------------------------------------

address = 'https://google.com/search?q='

# --- files ---

with open("ocr.txt") as f:
    newString = f.read()
newString = newString.replace("\n", " ").strip()

with open("ocr2.txt") as f:
    ans = f.read().splitlines()
ans1 = str(ans[0])
ans2 = str(ans[2])
ans3 = str(ans[4])

# --- info ---

quote_str = urllib.parse.quote_plus(newString)
full_url = address + quote_str

print()
print('full url:', full_url)
print()
print('newString:', newString)
print()
print("1.", ans1)
print("2.", ans2)
print("3.", ans3)
print()

# --- request ---

response = requests.get(full_url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'lxml')

for g in soup.find_all(class_='g'):

    url = 'https://google.com' + g.find('a')['href']
    print(url, '\n')

    webBlock = g.text # text without tags
    #webBlock = str(g)

    count1 = webBlock.count(ans1)
    count2 = webBlock.count(ans2)
    count3 = webBlock.count(ans3)

    ans1Score += count1
    ans2Score += count2
    ans3Score += count3


    if count1 + count2 + count3 == 0:
        do_something_with_page(url)


# --- results ---

print()
print('-----')
print(ans1, ":", ans1Score)
print(ans2, ":", ans2Score)
print(ans3, ":", ans3Score)
print('-----')
```